# YouTube thumbnail creator tool

Tags: image-editor, youtube

I have Photoshop and Gimp, but the main problem is, when I would like to publish a video I need to make a good thumbnail for I can raise awareness.

I know the perfect thumbnail size is 1270x720, but I have some things which I don't know, how it looks like after I published the video:

1. Where I can put text to the image for it can be perfectly visible?
2. What's the size of the text on thumbnail?
3. Where is the play button place on my thumbnail (because if I don't know, the play button cover up my text, and the result is very ugly)?

That's why I need a thumbnail editor tool, where I get a YouTube player layout, which shows everything what I need for making a perfect index image.

Comment: Youtube offers the ability to set the thumbnail based on the clip itself.

Also, you already do seem to have the tools required.

Comment: @LPChip That's not good enough.
I would like to make a custom thumbnail, and I need help for I can make it.
I maked 10 thubnail at tis time, and I'm very tired for this thing:
The text is too small, even when I use 32px, the play button cover up my texts, I need to fix this things somehow.
But I dosen't find any tool for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is to take a high resolution photo while making your video. You can then edit this photo with GIMP or PhotoShop to reduce its size to less than 2MB. YouTube actually allows 1920x1080p thumbnails so I would go for those instead. Personally, I use FireWorks to edit my thumbnails.
You can also use online image size reducers. I recommend http://www.reduceimages.com/

A custom thumbnail is better than taking YouTube's suggested thumbnails because YouTube seems to prefer videos with custom thumbnails in terms of search discovery.

You can also try [Canva](https://www.canva.com/) for templates

Comment: Oh thank you, finaly I have some clue, about this subject!

Answer (score 0):

I use [Picmaker](https://www.picmaker.io/) to create YouTube thumbnails. And I think this app can help you with all the problems you have to create a YouTube thumbnail.

1. You just have to click on create thumbnail and the size will automatically set to 1270x720.
2. Refer this blog to know about the size and best practices to create a thumbnail: https://blog.animaker.com/how-to-make-a-youtube-thumbnail/
3. There is a preview option in Picmaker which allows you to see how your thumbnail will look on YouTube.
4. Also, when you download the file, the size will be optimized so that it will be less than 2 MB. And don't worry the quality won't be affected.

Hope I was able to answer your question! :)